# How to render specified context in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have some context need to render in several pages,but no like nav and footer that render in every page.

How can I do it in .net core?

I googled and do not know which keyword I should use.Would you please help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,I found a easy way to do that:

First of all,create a razor page,such as:_aaa.cshtml,add the context you want to render in it.

Secondary,if you want to render it in index.cshtml,type following code in it:
@Html.Partial("_aaa.cshtml")

So it works.

I apologize for my stupid question.